# Spark Dataset transform method with a generic return type won't compile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following case classes with trait they are extend from

```
package com.mypackage.spark.event

case class TypedEvent(id: String, timestamp: Long, `type`: String)

sealed trait Event{
  def id: String
  def timestamp: Long
}

case class CreationEvent(id: String, timestamp: Long) extends Event

case class DeleteEvent(id: String, timestamp: Long) extends Event
```

I need to transform the Dataset of a specified type `TypedEvent` to another Dataset type that extends from `Event trait` using [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@transform[U](t:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) method in Dataset class with pattern matching mechanism as below(I'm using Spark 2.3.1) :

```
import spark.implicits._

val jsonDF = spark.read.json(pathToJsonFile)
val typedEventsDS = jsonDF.select("id", "timestamp", "type").as[TypedEvent]

val eventTypes = Array("CreateEvent", "DeleteEvent" , ...)

eventTypes.foreach(eventType => {
  val result = typedEventsDS.filter($"type" <=> eventType)
.transform(featurize(spark, eventType)) // line 61
  /**
   * ...
   */
})

def featurize (spark: SparkSession, eventType: String): Dataset[TypedEvent] => Dataset[_ <: Event] = dataset => {

  import spark.implicits._

  eventType match {
    case "CreateEvent" => dataset.as[CreationEvent]
    case "DeleteEvent" => dataset.as[DeleteEvent]
    ...
  }
}
```

The `featurize` method should return a Dataset of any Type that extends Event trait.

But this is not compiling with the error:

```
Error:(61, 12) no type parameters for method transform: (t:
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.mypackage.spark.event.TypedEvent] =>
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U] exist so 
that it can be applied to arguments 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.mypackage.spark.event.TypedEvent] =>
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_ <: com.mypackage.spark.event.Event])
--- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;

found:
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.mypackage.spark.event.TypedEvent] =>
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_ <: com.mypackage.spark.event.Event]
required:
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.mypackage.spark.event.TypedEvent] =>
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[?U]
      .transform(featurize(spark, eventType))
```

So I tried to add a type parameter to `transfrom` method itself as follow:

`.transform[_ <: Event](featurize(eventType))`
but that leads to another compilation error: 
`Error:(61, 22) unbound wildcard type .transform[_ <: Event](featurize(spark, eventType))`

Also tried to make the featurize method Generic :

```
  def featurize[T <: Event](spark: SparkSession, eventType: String): Dataset[TypedEvent] => Dataset[T] = 
dataset => { /* ... same ... */}
```

but got `type mismatch` on the first `case` clause

Nothing worked for me except removing `[_ <: ]` from `featurize` method and return the exact type (i.e., CreationEvent) I really don't know what's going on with Scala Generics. Any ideas?